# Firebase Cloud Messaging requireInteraction not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Reference: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

I have added the key-value pair:

```
"requireInteraction": true
```

But the notification in Desktop Chrome still disappear after 20 seconds. Does any one know if Firebase supports this key-value pair? Thanks!

My example below. Please change `[...]` to yours.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=[...]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "notification": {
    "requireInteraction": true,     
    "title": "This is custom title",
    "body": "this is custom body",
    "click_action": "https://google.com",
    "data" : {"requireInteraction": true  }
 },
  "to": "[...]",
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

Comment: Hi Samuel. I don't think that [`requireInteraction`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/notification-requireInteraction) is something that you should be setting in your payload. It should just be declared when you're *building* the notification. If the question is about just being supported, then `requireInteraction` doesn't belong in a `notification` payload, but *can exist* in a `data` payload. :)

Comment: @AL. I have tried to add requireInteraction: true in data payload or notification payload , but the notification popup in my chrome desktop still disappear after 20 seconds

Comment: One of the popup in below demo will not be closed until user click it.
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/notifications/requireInteraction.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firebase strips the `requireInteraction` property from the `notification` payload when the message is delivered. The workaround that works is to use the `data` property instead of the `notification`. You can then use the `setBackgroundMessageHandler()` method to build the notification as you want it to be:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    return self.registration.showNotification(payload.data.title,
        Object.assign({data: payload.data}, payload.data));
});
```

I've set `data` above, because the `click_action` no longer works with this approach and you need to register the desired onclick handler yourself. Here's a working service worker that does exactly what you intend with your set `notification`, but uses the data property instead:

```
// import scripts omitted 

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
// [END initialize_firebase_in_sw]

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', e => {
    let found = false;
    let f = clients.matchAll({
        includeUncontrolled: true,
        type: 'window'
    })
        .then(function (clientList) {
            for (let i = 0; i < clientList.length; i ++) {
                if (clientList[i].url === e.notification.data.click_action) {
                    // We already have a window to use, focus it.
                    found = true;
                    clientList[i].focus();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (! found) {
                clients.openWindow(e.notification.data.click_action).then(function (windowClient) {});
            }
        });
    e.notification.close();
    e.waitUntil(f);
});

// [START background_handler]
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here

    return self.registration.showNotification(payload.data.title,
        Object.assign({data: payload.data}, payload.data));

});
// [END background_handler]
```

Where this would be your curl call:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=yourKey-" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"data": {
    "title": "fooTitle",
    "body": "foo",
    "icon": "image.jpg",
    "click_action": "http://localhost:8000",
    "requireInteraction": true
  },
  "registration_ids": ["id1", "id2"]
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

Comment: is this still correct, I can't seem to get the notification to persist? I'm using firebase 4.3.0, the only difference between the curl request above and mine is that I still have the notification payload in it - so I have both data and notification

Comment: I think you need to decide for one. If I remember correctly, notification has precedence and data will only be used if there's no notification payload.

Comment: brilliant thanks, bud - removed the notification stuff and it worked like a charm

Comment: @bambam This works perfect.. but is there any way to get the notification to show even when the app is in focus?

Comment: @bambam : Any idea how to get new token after user clears cache . Also any idea to get unique browser id to save token in order to avoid duplication of token.

Thank you