# How to use requireInteraction for FCM browser push message

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

Am using FCM browser push notifications and it works fine. But the message shows up for few seconds and then disappears. I want it to show till user interacts with it.

When I googled I found about requireInteraction parameter. But am not sure how to set that from Java side when I call the fcm api to send a message. I would like to have my message show up with a 'Close' button, so that it stays there till user interacts with it.

Can you pls guide me on how to accomplish it? I tried to pass it as a parameter to push message similar to title, click_action etc, but it did not work. I tried passing that as a parameter in the curl option for testing, and it did not seem to work as well. We are using Angular4 for the client web app, which receives the push message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For folks who are looking for a solution, I found the solution in another SO post. [Firebase Cloud Messaging requireInteraction not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063675/firebase-cloud-messaging-requireinteraction-not-work)

The answer in that post works perfectly for me. Thanks to the author.